# Storing and retrieving values from JSP to servlet using Sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session, session-variables

I have login.jsp page where I try to username and password from text boxes are passed to servlet though session. The code o login.jsp is given below:

```
<form name="frm" action="DisplayData" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()" >
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">UserName:</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="username" value=""></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password"  name="password" value=""></input> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%
       String name = request.getParameter("username");
       String password = request.getParameter("password");
       session.setAttribute("name",name);
       session.setAttribute("pass", password);
    %>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="login">
            <td><input align="middle" type="submit" name="Sign_in" value="Sign_in"  onclick="return Validate()"></input></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Signup" onClick="javascript:window.location='Signup.jsp';"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I would like to retrieve the username and password that is set in login.jsp to servlet. I tried using the following code but it gives me null value. The java code I used in servlet is given below:

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
    System.out.println("Welcome"+name);
```

Could anyone tell me where I am making mistake. I Need the username to be stored in session so that I can make use of this for multiple request in that servlet

Comment: I dont recommend you to store username and password in session.

Comment: @JqueryLearner then what are the other ways is it request.getParameter()?

Comment: Have you created your session from the Servlet `HttpServletRequest` object? E.g. `HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);` if `req`was to be the `HttpServletRequest` object. Or did you even create a session before setting the attributes?

Comment: @Omoro Hi I used the following code "HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);"

Comment: @deena why are you creating `HttpSession` with a `true` argument just before you want to extract `name`. The `true` means `initialise a session if there isn't already one set up` and you mostly do that before setting the session-attributes and hardly when you want to get the attributes.

Comment: Use HttpSession=request.getSession(false);

Comment: @Naveen I tried the following but still the value is null. "HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);                   String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
System.out.println("Welcome"+name);"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null being returned from `session.getAttribute("name")` because you are setting the **name** attribute in the session when the jsp is rendered. At this time, the username is not entered. What you need to do is get the username using `getParameter()` in the servlet and save it in the session if you want.

Comment: Thanks Priyesh for your comment. I obtained the value using getParamter fro username and Password and it works fine. Now as you said I need the these two values to be stored in session so that I want to use the username and password for other methods. here is my code for getting usernamdne and password                    "username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");"