# How to get all values from a select box(selected & not selected) in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a HTML select box which have multi select enabled in my jsp. I'm populating options for that dynamically from other button. So user won't be selecting any values from that select box. I have to pass all the values of my selectbox to other jsp.

I'm navigating through jsp using form action submit. When doing that I cannot able to get all my select box values.

```
request.getParameterValues
```

This one giving only the selected values from that multi-select box. What I want is to get all values from that selectbox no matter selected or not.

Thanks;

Comment: - Use Web Storage for this

Answer (score 0):

Well simply loop through your select and get every option value, try the following:

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
for(var i=0; i<select.options.length;i++){
    console.log(select.options[i].value);
}
```

This is [**a DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ma0m97d0/).

Comment: No I want to get all values in my next jsp from `request` object. Is my question clear enough?

Comment: Why would you do that?? you can simply insert the same HTML of your select in your next page. because `getParameter`and  `getParameterValues` will not take all the selct options.

Comment: What you mean by insert the same HTML to next page.? How would I insert that?

Comment: from what I understood you want to have the values of the select in your next page, so just copy the select html code into the second page ( and give it a `display:none;` style) and use javascript to get the options values.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `Web Storage` for store the value and getting back that value form `Web Storage`.

For more detail you can visit below links.

- [Create a localStorage name/value pair](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
- [Example: for Web Storage](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_storage.htm)

**Code Below**

- you can store data in 1st Page (Html1.html) as below code :

`localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

- you can get the data on 2nd Page (Html2.html) as below code :

`var valueFromFirstPage = localStorage.getItem("key");`

Comment: @sagar kaware  - Use Web Storage for this

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of values to the `HttpSession` and retrieve them wherever you need for the user `session`.

In your jsp ,

```
 HttpSession session =request.getSession(false);
 session.setAttribute("ListName", yourListHere);
```

to set the values to the `session` and to retrieve them,

```
session.getAttribute("ListName");
```

**Related:**

- [Storing and retrieving values from JSP to servlet using Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563961/storing-and-retrieving-values-from-jsp-to-servlet-using-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

In your first jsp, have a hidden field with all possible values for the select box, so that on the next jsp you will have the values by the given name, of-course name will be different for hidden field and the select box.

***CSV hidden***

**first.jsp**

```
<select name='chosen' multiple>
  ...
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='toChoose' value='1,2,3,4'/>
```

**next.jsp**

```
String[] chosen = request.getParameterValues("chosen");
String[] toChoose = request.getParameter("toChoose").split(",");
```

***multiple hidden***

**first.jsp**

```
<select name='chosen' multiple>
  ...
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='toChoose' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='toChoose' value='2'/>
....
```

**next.jsp**

```
String[] chosen = request.getParameterValues("chosen");
String[] toChoose = request.getParameterValues("toChoose");
```