# How to check whether a user is logged in for the first time after registered in my website?

Tags: jsp

I've a Landing page in my website. I've to display a greeting message of welcome, 'username' in that page if the user is logged in for the first time in my website after successful registration. Also if the user is logged in 2nd time or more to the website the message should be welcome back 'username'. I've to do this in my JSP page.Can anybody suggest a solution? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect the user to the `landing page` after sucessfull registration with the greeting message.

For the normal logins , use the custom messages as you `"welcome back 'username'"` . If you wish to display the username through out the session , put it in the `HttpSession` and show it to the user.

Another old school approach is to use the database for this. you can update the number of user logins with a separate column and display the messages accordingly

**see also**

- [Storing and retrieving values from JSP to servlet using Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563961/storing-and-retrieving-values-from-jsp-to-servlet-using-sessions)
- [HttpSession Tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Create a database table for login records when your login successfully update login count in table. Using this method you now each your how many time login on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Here can be a lot of solution as per application requirement.

1) if you redirect user after successful registration in your site. you can add flag value in url and if that value is available in URL means user are just register. show your massage base on that flag value.

2) If you use email confirmation for active user you can send flag from email confirmation to display massage.

3) If you enable user if only email is confirm. then you can set flag massage just before set user status enable.